# Could not devise a query plan for the given query for full outer join

Tags: sql, join, amazon-redshift

What is wrong with this query ?
I am trying to execute the given query on Redshift but I am getting error "Could not get Query Plan"

My Query is like this :

(select distinct x,y,a2.z from a1
full outer join (select distinct z from a1) a2  on 1=1) ;

One more thing, Can I use cross join instead of full outer join since I have no join predicates or where clause.

Comment: pick one server product and not 4. please.

Comment: cross join won't be the same if either one of the inputs is empty

Comment: Oh actually it will be because they are both `a1` anyway - so it is not possible for one side to be empty and the other to have rows

Comment: So, in this scenario there will be no difference between cross join and full outer joins? Correct?

Comment: yes - in this specific scenario, If it was `A CROSS JOIN B` vs `A FULL JOIN B ON 1=1` then they would behave differently if just one of them was empty but that does not apply here

Comment: But, why Redshift can not determine the query plan for full join with 1=1?

Comment: no idea, does the rewrite work?

Comment: Yes, rewrite with Cross Join is working fine.

Comment: Just have to wait for someone familiar with redshift to explain then

Comment: Give the exact text of the error. You have already given 2 versions here. What exact systems/layers/APIs are you using & how are your running your code? Give your DDL. [mre]

Comment: Read the PostgreSQL & Redshift documentation re the GEQO & its parameters.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I asked question after I exhausted all my other  options.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about Amazon redshift but this has the same semantics as the original query and is IMO clearer so see if it can produce a plan for this

```
SELECT xy.x,
       xy.y,
       z.z
FROM   (SELECT DISTINCT x,
                        y
        FROM   a1) xy
       CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT z
                   FROM   a1) z
```

Comment: Great! I will try this. Thank you.